# Parsing SSH stream from batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh, cmd

Using batch script to run ssh, I am finding all the output is dumped into the standard error... so my command:

```
ssh -i keyfile user@host "commands" 2> error.log
```

captures the remote server prompt for password if there are no matching keys in the local known_hosts...
This leaves me no way to capture the output for error processing or logging without leaving the user of my batch script stuck no knowing what the blank prompt is.

My other thought is to do a simple ssh to test the connection first and establish the password prompt if it's needed, then move to the command of interest. But I feel like if the first one passes, then the only thing I'm error is my remote command.

I've tried

```
>CON 2> error.log
```

... seems to do the same thing.

Unfortunately there's no TEE command default in Windows.

My best solution is to:
1) echo Enter password
2) ssh "params" 2>error.log

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If the remote system supports the syntax, you could do something like this:

```
ssh -i keyfile user@host "commands 2>&1" > output.log 2> error.log
```

This redirects the remote command's error output to its standard output. `ssh`'s own standard output and standard error aren't affected. The `2>&1` part is Bourne shell syntax to redirect standard error (descriptor 2) to standard output (descriptor 1). It should work if the remote shell is sh, bash, or ksh.

Comment: that still redirects all output to the log including password prompts